# Record IOS Simulator video and simulator audio in background

Tags: ios, xcode, ffmpeg, ios-simulator, video-capture

I need to record 100 separate videos of my simulator which is about 40 hours of high quality. I want to record video of Xcode simulator and system audio in the background. Since I need to use my computer at the same time I don't want to use tools like Camtasia or quick time. I am wondering if this is achievable. If so this will save my one month.

Comment: There is not currently any way to record audio. Please do file an enhancement request at https://bugreport.apple.com.

Answer (score 9):

In the latest version of Xcode Simulators "Scroll over the **Save Screen** Button and Hold the **OPTION** key , gives the screen record option.
[image]

**Save screen button will change to record video button**

[image]

Comment: This is the way to go! Given how hidden it is, makes me wonder how long it's been there.

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve this by following.

1.In simulator Menu Choose Hardware > Audio Input > System to use the same audio input as the Mac.

2.Open Terminal and navigate to the directory where you want to save video.

Run Command : `xcrun simctl io booted recordVideo <filename>.<extension>`

It will start recording.To finish Press `Control-C`. Video will save on current directory.

Comment: have you set input device in sound preference?

Comment: sound of simulator? yes

Comment: sound preference of mac. In system preference>sound>input .    OR type sound on spotlite search.

Comment: I think have the same problem as @birdcage. I am trying to record a video of the simulator and I am using the command under point 2 in this answer. However, I can record the video just fine, but I am not able to record the audio coming from the app running in the simulator. Should this be possible?

Comment: It seems _recordVideo_ only records video -- there is no audio track in the output file.